# Creating cluster first and then Adding node to it using HereMap JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, android, maps, here-api

On Android, I am creating cluster on HereMaps and Adding nodes to it using below function on HereMaps Java API.

```
   private void initializeMapCluster() {

       truckImage = new com.here.android.mpa.common.Image();
        try {
            truckImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.truck_img);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

       markerCluster = new ClusterLayer();
        // Setting up basic cluster theme.
        BasicClusterStyle redStyle = new BasicClusterStyle();
        redStyle.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        BasicClusterStyle greenStyle = new BasicClusterStyle();
        greenStyle.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);

       ClusterTheme theme = new ClusterTheme();
        theme.setStyleForDensityRange(4, 9, redStyle);
        theme.setStyleForDensityRange(10, 49, greenStyle);
        markerCluster.setTheme(theme);
        map.addClusterLayer(markerCluster);
        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(LAT, LNG, 0.0), Map.Animation.BOW);
        LocationUpdated(LAT, LNG);
    }
```

Now, I am willing to do the same but not able to find similar functions using HereMaps JavaScript API.

Though, I am able to do clustering by DataPoints but I am looking for an option of creating cluster first and then Adding node to it using JavaScript API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternate solution to this problem in JavaScript API of HereMaps. I Hope this can help someone facing similar issue.

**Step 1 : Create a Cluster Data Provider with empty array :**

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider([], {
      clusteringOptions: {
        eps: 32,
        minWeight: 2
      }
    });
```

**Step 2 : Create a Clustering Layer with Cluster Data Provider :**

```
var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
```

**Step 3 : Add Clustering Layer to Map :**

```
map.addLayer(clusteringLayer)
```

**Step 4 : Dynamically add / remove Data Points to / from Cluster Data Provider**

```
var dataPoint1 = new H.clustering.DataPoint(lat1, lng1);
var dataPoint2 = new H.clustering.DataPoint(lat2, lng2);
clusteredDataProvider.addDataPoint(dataPoint1);
clusteredDataProvider.addDataPoint(dataPoint2);
clusteredDataProvider.removeDataPoint(dataPoint1);
```